# Finding four of a kind in a 5 card game

Tags: java, string, poker

I am trying to find four of kind in a 5 poker hand. I don't know where I went wrong, but the JUnit is reporting it's wrong.

```
public boolean hasFourOfaKind(String hand) {
    int counter = 0;
    char x = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < hand.length(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < hand.length(); j++) {
            if (i == 0) {
                x = hand.charAt(0);
                counter++;
            } else if (x == hand.charAt(i)) {
                counter++;

            }
        }
    }
    if (counter >= 4) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the format of String which `hand` will hold? BTW `if (condition){ return true; }else{ return false;}` is same as `return condition;`.

Comment: how do you use `i` in line `if(i==0)` without definition...

Comment: All of your cards are represented as single chars ? How do you represent 10 for example?

Comment: Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with more details.

Comment: Please note that Java and JavaScript are completely different languages. @coolstoner `i` is defined and declared in the outer `for` loop.

Comment: i saw the edit made now....it wasnt there when i was adding my comment....

Comment: then what should i do to make this program work. Newbie and confused

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do, but having a loop variable `j` that is never used is not a good sign.

Comment: I don't understand the code. How do you distinguish the "kinds"? It seems that x is the counted kind, but x is always the same, the first kind of hand.  Additionally, it seems strange to me that j is not used.

Comment: am trying to find four of a kind.

Comment: Do change if (counter >= 4) for if (counter >= 3) you are not counting when i=0.

Comment: Four of kind means four or more cards can be same right?? "JJJJJ" or "JJKJJ" will return true in this case??

Comment: You don't seem to be using `j` for anything.  Was that intentional?

Comment: Incidentally, if this happened to me, I would step through the failing unit test with a debugger.  If I did this, I'd be able to see immediately what was going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop logic is wrong. It is incrementing counter for the same card again. That's why it is failing. In below mentioned code I am considering card only once.

```
public static boolean hasFourOfaKind(String hand) {
    int counter = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < hand.length(); i++) {
        counter = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < hand.length(); j++) {
            if (hand.charAt(j) == hand.charAt(i)) {
                counter++;
            }
        }
        if (counter >= 4) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Yea i have tried that before too but the Junit is reporting it wrong idk why. Even to this code above it reported it wrong

Comment: Code you posted above was giving wrong output for some cases but I think above code is passing all the cases. Can you paste your junit code?

Comment: i will put it as part of the question because its too long to paste it here.

Comment: You can separate your junit test case for this specific case?? You will be using some assert statements. Or you can use syso before and after you calling above method and tell me what you got?

Comment: `public void testFourOfAKind() {
        java.util.Random rng = new java.util.Random(SEED);
        Adler32 check = new Adler32();
        for(int i = 0; i < RUNS; i++) {
            String hand = createHand(rng, 5);
            check.update(cp.hasFourOfAKind(hand) ? i : ~i);
        }
        assertEquals(check.getValue(), 3699029383L);
    }`

Comment: assertEquals(cp.hasFourOfAKind(hand), true); ? Can you test something like that.

Answer (score 0):

a real quickie on this since you wanted to test your hand assuming its a string of characters and below code is rewritten in javascript since i see the JS tag for the question too.....

```
function hasFourOfaKind(hand) {
    var counter = 0;
    var set_of_four = [];

    for (i = 0; i < hand.length; i++) {
        if (i == 0) {
            x = hand.charAt(0);
            set_of_four.push(x);
            counter++;
        } else {
            x = hand.charAt(i);
            if(set_of_four.indexOf(x) != '-1'){
                counter++;
            } else {
                set_of_four = set_of_four.splice(-1,1);
                set_of_four.push(x);
                counter = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    return (counter >= 3);
}

var poker_hand = 'BAAAAA';
var result = hasFourOfaKind(poker_hand);
console.log(result);
```

@Dmitry: thanks for the correction earlier...i was in too much haste then......

Comment: that is Java question, not JS. Moreover your code is wrong and doesn't work as expected (try "BAAAA")

Answer (score 0):

I assume your `hand` is represented as something like "ABCDE". Your code is wrong. Let's take a look at the inner loop body:

```
for (int i = 0; i < hand.length(); i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < hand.length(); j++) {
        if (i == 0) {  // take a look at this line
            x = hand.charAt(0);
            counter++;
        } else if (x == hand.charAt(i)) {
            counter++;

        }
    }
}
```

I've commented the line you should look at. The `i` will be always be 0 at first outer loop iteration so you'll increase your counter `hand.length()` times (that's how many times inner loop will execute while `i == 0`). If your hand length is 4 or more your method will always return `true`. Moreover even if you'll fix this part it won't help as you're always comparing chars to the first char of the string.

As a suggestion you can get a char array from your string, sort it and look how many identical chars are going one by one:

```
private boolean hasFourOfaKind(String hand) {
    if (hand == null || hand.length() == 0) {
        return false;
    }
    char[] chars = hand.toCharArray();
    Arrays.sort(chars);
    char current = chars[0];
    int count = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i < chars.length; i++) {
        char next = chars[i];
        if (current != next) {
            current = next;
            count = 1;
        } else {
            count++;
            if (count == 4) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```